# Use jquery to make an object visible in real time at a given time and day

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an object on my page which is supposed to be invisible most of the time. However, it becomes visible on sundays from 9 to 11pm. This is the code in PHP im using:

```
<?php
 $day=date('w'); 
 $hour=date('Gi'); 
 if($day=="0" && $hour>2100 && $hour<2359) { $playoff=1; } else $playoff=0;
?>

<object style="<?php if ($playoff==0) { echo "display:none"; ?>" ></object>
```

However, if users are on the page before that time and dont reload it, they wont be able to see the object. Thats why i need something that triggers it visible once the time comes without having to reload the page.  Must this be done with jquery? How can i do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With HTMl5 you can use Javascript Web Workers.

Here is a example:

```
$(function() {

var worker = new Worker('scripts/task.js'); //External script
worker.onmessage = function(event) {    //Method called by external script

    if(event.data.show) {
        $("#message").show();
    } else {
        $("#message").hide();
    }       
};
```

});

And you task.js file:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date();

    if(now.getDay() == 0 && (now.getHours() >= 21 && now.getHours() <= 23)) {
        postMessage({show: true});
    } else {
        postMessage({show: false});
    }   

},60000); //repeat after 1 minutes
```

See this article http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp  to understand how web workers operate.

Note Web workers are supported by: Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Comment: hi, im just concerned about the loop. Wont it cause an overload in the server?

Comment: this code does not go on the server only runs on client

Comment: The problem is if the the date and time of the user's computer is wrong, then do not show correctly. You can fix this by getting the server time. But if the user is in a different timezone from the server, it would be displayed in accordance with the date and time of the server and not the user's.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $day=date('w'); 
   $hour=date('Gi'); 
   if($day=="0" && $hour>2100 && $hour<2359) { $playoff=1; } else $playoff=0;

   echo $playoff;

?>
```

HTML

```
<object id="hideOrShowMe"></object>
```

JQUERY

```
$.get("scriptAbovePageName.php", function( data ) {
  if(data == 1){
    $('#hideOrShowMe').css("display", "block");
}else{
    $('#hideOrShowMe').css("display", "none");
});
```

The only thing left to do with the above is put it in a loop (call the `$.get` every minute or second etc.)- but I am not writing all your code for you :-D

**ADDITIONAL**

The best way of doing this would be to get the servers date and time when the page loads and then get difference between users computer time and server time and adjust users date and time by this amount.

WE WANT TO SHOW WHEN time 9-11 and day of week = 1

Page loads - server time is 8 (to make it easy to understand) and day of week is 3

Check server time vs local time - local is 9 and date is 4

then store adjustment variable locally (time -1 (8 - 9) and date - 1)

Then do javascript loop every 60 seconds getting local time.

So later on:

local time = 12 and local date = 2 -> adjust to 11 and 1 and then check against the fixed 9pm to 11pm on a Sunday

However for a beginner this is a bit complex so answer above will work fine unless you have thousands of users and only call the script every minute or so (interval of 6000 etc.)

Comment: That sounds good, but im concerned about using loops because that could cause a server overload, couldnt it?

Comment: editted my answer to answer this as it is a bit long :-P

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this. You can check date without PHP.

**HTML:**

```
 <object id="show_me" ></object>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function myTimer(){
    var d = new Date();
    if((d.getDay() == 0) && (21 < d.getHours() ) && (d.getHours() < 24)){
        $("#show_me").show();
    }else{
        $("#show_me").hide();
    }     
}

setInterval(function(){myTimer();},10000); // check every 10 seconds
```

Hope this helps:

Comment: Thanks, im just a little concerned about the loop. Can it cause a server overload considering i have a lot of users seeing the page at the same time?

Comment: Thank you. This is a simple client-side script, which is executed by the user's web browser, and doesn't cause server overload at all.

Comment: Sorry about the late answer. Its good to know that but even so, wont the script make the users browser collapse after having it reload so many times the same thing?